# How to flash a RichTextBox border and background colors in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Seems like this should be fairly simple, as it is in Winforms, but I'm relatively new to WPF so still trying to change thinking how data and UI interact.

**Scenario:** User clicks a button on my main form. The button is used to enter a street address. In the street address form, I do some basic data validation when the user clicks a submit button. Submit() iterates through each of the data entry fields and calls the method below to attempt to alert the user to the offending data field.

Here's the code I have that doesn't do anything that I can detect:

```
    private void FlashTextBox(RichTextBox box)
    {
        var currentBorderColor = box.BorderBrush;
        var currentBackgroundColor = box.Background;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {

                    box.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    box.BorderBrush = Brushes.IndianRed;
                    box.InvalidateVisual();

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                    box.BorderBrush = currentBorderColor;
                    box.Background = currentBackgroundColor;
                    box.InvalidateVisual();

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted is completely wrong. The main issue is that you block the UI thread while you modify the properties in question, so of course their appearance will never visibly change. The only thread that's allowed to update the screen isn't being allowed to run. But, you are also mucking around with a UI element directly (`box`), and hard-coding UI attributes (colors). ...

Comment: ... The right way to do this is to use MVVM (I'm guessing the rest of your program is similarly broken), then in the view model have a `bool` property that indicates whether the highlight should be set, then in the XAML have a style that is triggered by the `bool` property to set the border and background color as desired, and then in the code-behind, write a background task method that does the loop and updates the view model's property. For extra credit, use an animation defined in XAML instead of C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've noted [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403045/how-to-flash-a-richtextbox-border-and-background-colors-in-wpf#comment101288794_57403045), the primary issue with your code is that you have blocked the UI thread. So, while you are changing the properties of interest to new values in a loop, the actual UI never gets a chance to update the visual representation, i.e. what's on the screen.

Ironically, while you note *"Seems like this should be fairly simple, as it is in Winforms"*, had you tried to write the same code in a Winforms program, you would have had the exact same problem. Both Winforms and WPF (and indeed, most GUI APIs) have exactly this same limitation: there's one thread that handles all of the UI, and after you change one or more data values that should affect how the UI looks, you have to return control to the UI thread that called you, so that it can then update the screen.

Now, you note also that you are *"trying to change thinking how data and UI interact"*. This is a good thing, and if you are willing to take the time to learn the MVVM concepts WPF was designed to work with, that will help a lot. Winforms also has a data binding model, and you can in fact write very similar code in Winforms as is *strongly* encouraged for WPF. But, WPF's "retained" graphics model as opposed to Winform's "immediate" model — i.e. WPF keeps track of what your graphics are supposed to look like, while Winform demands that you handle drawing the graphics yourself every time the screen needs updating — lends itself much better to the data binding approach, and WPF's entire design is based on that.

This means that you should work hard to keep your data where the data goes, and your UI where the UI goes. I.e. data is in your code-behind, and UI is in the XAML. It's a good idea in both APIs, but you're sacrificing a lot more if you fail to do it with WPF.

So where does that leave your question? Well, lacking a good [minimal, complete, and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to know what your code looks like, and so what would be the best way to fix it. So instead, I'll provide a couple of examples in the hopes that after you reorient your code to fit the WPF paradigm better, you can apply one as you see fit. (Unfortunately, one of the things I don't like much about WPF is that in some ways it's *too* powerful, offering many different ways to accomplish the same result; this can make it really hard sometimes to know what is the best way.)

These two examples differ from each other in how much code-behind they require. The first puts the animation logic into the C# code, as part of the view model. On the one hand, this is arguably less "the WPF way". But the second, which uses the view code (i.e. the XAML) to define the animation, requires a tiny bit of extra plumbing in the view's code-behind, which bugs me a little, as it blurs the line between view and view model a bit more than I'd like.

Oh well.

Here's the view model class for the first approach:

```cs
class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _text, value);
    }

    private bool _isHighlighted;
    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get => _isHighlighted;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _isHighlighted, value);
    }

    private bool _isAnimating;
    public bool IsAnimating
    {
        get => _isAnimating;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _isAnimating, value, _OnIsAnimatingChanged);
    }

    private void _OnIsAnimatingChanged(bool oldValue)
    {
        _toggleIsHighlightedCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        _animateIsHighlightedCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private readonly DelegateCommand _toggleIsHighlightedCommand;
    private readonly DelegateCommand _animateIsHighlightedCommand;

    public ICommand ToggleIsHighlightedCommand => _toggleIsHighlightedCommand;
    public ICommand AnimateIsHighlightedCommand => _animateIsHighlightedCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _toggleIsHighlightedCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => IsHighlighted = !IsHighlighted, () => !IsAnimating);
        _animateIsHighlightedCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => _FlashIsHighlighted(this), () => !IsAnimating);
    }

    private static async void _FlashIsHighlighted(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.IsAnimating = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            viewModel.IsHighlighted = !viewModel.IsHighlighted;
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }

        viewModel.IsAnimating = false;
    }
}

class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute?.Invoke() != false;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute?.Invoke();
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The second class there, `NotifyPropertyChangedBase`, is just my standard base class for my view models. It contains all the boilerplate to support the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. There are WPF frameworks that include such a base class themselves; why WPF doesn't itself provide one, I don't know. But it's handy to have, and between it and a Visual Studio code snippet to paste in the property template, it makes it a lot faster to put together the view models for a program.

Similarly, the third class, `DelegateCommand`, makes it easier to define `ICommand` objects. Again, this type of class is available in third-party WPF frameworks as well. (I also have a version of the class that is generic with the type parameter specifying the type of the command parameter passed to the `CanExecute()` and `Execute()` methods, but since we don't need that here, I didn't bother to include it.

As you can see, once you get past the boilerplate, the code's pretty simple. It has a pro-forma `Text` property just so I have something to bind to the `TextBox` in my UI. It also has a couple of `bool` properties that relate to the visual state of the `TextBox`. One determines the actual visual state, while the other provides some indication as to whether that state is currently being animated.

There are two `ICommand` instances providing user interaction with the view model. One just toggles the visual state, while the other causes the animation you want to happen.

Finally, there's the method that actually does the work. It first sets the `IsAnimating` property, then loops ten times to toggle the `IsHighlighted` property. This method uses `async`. In a Winforms program, this would be essential, so that the UI property updates happened in the UI thread. But in this WPF program, it's optional. I like the async/await programming model, but for simple property-change notifications, WPF will marshal the binding update back to the UI thread as necessary, so you could in fact just create a background task in the thread pool or a dedicated thread to handle the animation.

(For the animation, I used 200 ms between frames instead of 100 as your code would've, just because I think it looks better, and in any case makes it easier to see what the animation is doing.)

Note that the view model itself has no idea there's a UI involved per se. It just has a property that indicates whether the text box should be highlighted or not. It's up to the UI to figure out how to do that.

And that, looks like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO57403045FlashBorderBackground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO57403045FlashBorderBackground"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding ToggleIsHighlightedCommand}" Content="Toggle Control" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding AnimateIsHighlightedCommand}" Content="Flash Control" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Width="100" Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <TextBox.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="IndianRed"/>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style.Triggers>
        </p:Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This just sets some default values for the border and background colors. And then, importantly, it defines a data trigger that will temporarily override these defaults any time the condition in the data trigger is true. That is, the declared binding evaluates to the declared value given (which in my example above is in fact the `bool` value of `true`).

Every place you see an element property set to something that looks like `{Binding}`, that's a reference back to the current data context, which in this case is set to my view model class.

Now, WPF has a very rich animation feature set, and that can be used instead of the above to handle the flashing animation. If we're going to do it that way, then the view model can be simpler, as we don't need the explicit property for the highlighted state. We do still need the `IsAnimating` property, but this time instead of the "animate" command calling a method, which sets this property as a side-effect, the command sets the property directly and does nothing else (and that property, now the primary controller for the animation, still does serve as the flag so that the button's command can be enabled/disabled as needed):

```cs
class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _text, value);
    }

    private bool _isAnimating;
    public bool IsAnimating
    {
        get => _isAnimating;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _isAnimating, value, _OnIsAnimatingChanged);
    }

    private void _OnIsAnimatingChanged(bool oldValue)
    {
        _animateIsHighlightedCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private readonly DelegateCommand _animateIsHighlightedCommand;

    public ICommand AnimateIsHighlightedCommand => _animateIsHighlightedCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _animateIsHighlightedCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => IsAnimating = true, () => !IsAnimating);
    }
}
```

Importantly, you'll notice that now the view model doesn't contain any code to actually run the animation. That, we'll find in the XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO57403045FlashBorderBackground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO57403045FlashBorderBackground"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="flashBorder" RepeatBehavior="5x"
                Completed="flashStoryboard_Completed">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.4">
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="IndianRed"/>
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.4">
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Red"/>
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Black"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding AnimateIsHighlightedCommand}" Content="Flash Control" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Width="100" Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <TextBox.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimating}" Value="True">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource flashBorder}" Name="flashBorderBegin"/>
              </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flashBorderBegin"/>
              </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style.Triggers>
        </p:Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In this case, there's a `Storyboard` object which contains two animation sequences (both are started simultaneously) that do the actual flashing of the control. The storyboard itself lets you specify how many times it should repeat (`"5x"` in this case, for five times), and then within each animation sequence, the duration of the whole sequence (400 ms, since one sequence involves two states, each displayed for 200 ms), and then the "key frames" that dictate what actually happens during the animation, each specifying at what time during the animation it should take effect.

Then, in the text box's style, instead of triggering property setters, the storyboard is started and stopped according to the trigger state (entered or exited).

Note that in the storyboard, the `Completed` event is subscribed to. Whereas in the previous example, there was no change to the default `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file, for this version there's a little bit of code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = (ViewModel)DataContext;
    }

    private void flashStoryboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.IsAnimating = false;
    }
}
```

This has the implementation of the event handler for the `Storyboard.Completed` event. And since that handler is going to need to modify the view model state, there is now code to retrieve the view model from the `DataContext` property and save it in a field so that the event handler can get at it.

This event handler is what allows the `IsAnimating` property to be set back to `false` once the animation has completed.

So, there you go. It is possible that there's a better way to do this, but I think these two examples should give you a good place to start in terms of seeing how things "ought to be done" in WPF.

(I'll admit, the one thing that really bugs me about the animation approach is that I'd rather not have to explicitly state in the storyboard the original colors for the text box; but I'm not aware of any way to specify a key frame in the `<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrame/>` element that instead of actually setting a new color, just *removes* whatever changes the animation had already applied.)